# Runtime memory is growing abnormally even if I reuse bitmap

Tags: android, android-image, android-bitmap

In `onActivityResult()` in camera for picking the gallery image I am doing like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

where the imageUri file is of some 7.0MB so I am creating bitmap of smaller size where I am assigning it to same bitmap:

```
bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,screenWidth,screenHeight/2, true)
```

but the runtime memory is growing abnormally at that time where the memory allocated for 7.0 MB bitmap is not releasing, is GC not collecting the previously allocated space? Or what else could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, screenWidth, screenHeight/2, true);
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap = null;
```

**Note:** Memory allocation of 7mb is normal at first. You are getting a bitmap about 7mb. But you should recycle it after you scaled it down to a new bitmap. Then you can see that 7mb allocation is decreased. After this you should see only your scaled bitmap's size allocated at memory.

Comment: I was following the same procedure but I dint assigned null after recycling, but I dint see any deallocation of memory

Comment: Deallocation is going to be at first garbage collection. Or if you want to see that instantly you can call System.gc(); after assigning null to the bitmap.

Comment: I dint worked to me though I assigned null I dint see any deallocation of memory allocated for 'bitmap' variable which is holding some 7.0 MB data